# Is symbol in Ruby and JavaScript have the same purpose?

Tags: javascript, ruby, typescript, language-design

Is `Symbol` in Ruby and JavaScript (maybe some other programming languages which also have an equivalent type) have the same purpose from a programming-language-design perspective? (Question #1)

I know that both of those two languages have `Symbol` type.

`Symbol` in both language can be used to retrieve methods from an object:

```js
const a = [];
a[Symbol.iterator] // [Function: values]
```

```rb
a = []
a.method(:at) => #<Method: Array#at(_)>
```

Symbols in Ruby are unique :

```rb
:a.object_id => 776028
:a.object_id => 776028
```

In JavaScript, symbols created with `Symbol.for` are kept in an internal dictionary which make it kind of `unique`:

```js
Symbol.for('a') === Symbol.for('a') // true
```

But `Symbol(..)` always return a new symbol regardless what the parameter is:

```js
// Why this is designed this way? Question #2
Symbol('a') === Symbol('a') // false
```

Comment: Why is this relevant?

Comment: _"Why this is designed this way?"_ Because: _"[`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) is a built-in object whose constructor returns a symbol primitive — also called a Symbol value or just a Symbol — **that’s guaranteed to be unique**."_, _"Every `Symbol()` call is **guaranteed to return a unique Symbol**."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are kind of opposites of each other. Ruby's `Symbol` guarantees that it is *always the same*. ECMAScript's `Symbol` guarantees that it is *always different*.

Ruby's `Symbol` is used to represent the concept of a "name" or a "label" in the same way that `Array` is used to represent the concept of "a sequence of things" or `String` is used to represent the concept of "text". Ruby's `Symbol`s are often described as "immutable `String`s", but they are actually much closer to `Integer`s than they are to `String`s. (`Integer`s are also immutable, are also immediate, are also unique, and `Intege` literals also evaluate to themselves.) In fact, in earlier versions of Ruby, `Symbol`s and `Fixnum`s (fixed-size `Integer`s) were closely related and could even be converted to each other. The drive to make `Symbol`s more `String`-like is a rather recent (15 years) phenomenon.

ECMAScript's `Symbol` is an *unforgeable token*. This concept comes from capability-based security. Mark Miller, one of the foremost researchers on capability-based security and object-capability-based security and designer of the E capability-based programming language, is one of the TC39 committee members that is driving the security aspects of ECMAScript design, including Realms and Symbols, so that is not terribly surprising.

Because an ECMAScript `Symbol` is always different, it is *impossible* for you to generate a `Symbol` that is equal to my `Symbol`. (That's what "unforgeable token" means.) So, if I use a `Symbol` to protect access to something, I can be 100% sure that *nobody* can get access, *unless* I have explicitly handed them "my" `Symbol`. The `Symbol` becomes an "access capability", hence "capability-based security".

If you want to actually re-use a `Symbol`, you have to make sure to explicitly "remember" it. That's what `Symbol.for` does for you: it remembers the `Symbol` for you, and gives it back to you when you ask for it. That way, it essentially implements the semantics of Ruby's `Symbol`, and can be used that way.

Another example are the "well-known `Symbols`", such as `Symbol.iterator`. This is just a method which always returns the same `Symbol` – the `Symbol` is opaque and unforgeable, so you would never be able to recreate it yourself. These methods also essentially just "remember" a specific `Symbol` for you.

But that is not the primary use case for `Symbol`s in ECMAScript. The primary use case is capability-based security. (You can kind of think of it as a key, but that's also a flawed analogy because keys can be copied, and they can be forged – `Symbol`s can't.)

Comment: Re question #2: The `Symbol` function always returns a unique Symbol, regardless of the symbol description you provide. That's the primary purpose of Symbols: uniqueness. For instance, if two different libraries both use `Symbol("stuff")` in their code, it's by design (and a Good Thing™) that those are *different* symbols even if both libraries are used in the same page/app. `Symbol.for` is specifically for those cases where it's preferable for those symbols to be the same -- for instance, ...

Comment: ...because you might pass an object using that symbol as a property key between two different JavaScript realms (a page and a frame within it, for instance, or a page and a web worker) and want the code in both realms to be referring to the same property.

Comment: I don't think the "primary use case" in JavaScript is capability-based security, but it's certainly *a* use case. Uniqueness was needed for other reasons as well: Adding fundamental features like iterability without fear that (for example) whatever name was chosen for the "give me an iterator" method would conflict with userland code.